# Performance/Health checking queries for a user with Read permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am a software developer that only had read access to our prod database (of course).

Occasionally we have what looks like performance issues on our server when my DBAs are not available.

**Is there any kind of query I can run (with Data Reader permissions only) that could tell me anything about the current health of my SQL Server?**

If there was some kind of edge permission that did not allow for changing data or schema that would help, I could probably get permissions to that.  (For example, I was given permissions to monitor replication in our production environment.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have your DBAs create

- [Adam Machanic's - sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com)
- [Brent's - sp_AskBrent](http://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/)

and grant execute permission to you.

That should be a good starting point to find out why your sql server is slow.

Note: Brent has already mentioned on How to Grant Permissions to Non-DBAs. You can follow that method to ask your DBA to grant permissions to you.

Comment: +1 nice job, @kin. you got the whoisactive link before me :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain about what you are seeking. You want a "health check" but that may not always tell you why ***this*** particular query (whichever query you're running at the moment) is suddenly exhibiting performance issues. There is a [`system_health`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877955.aspx) event session ([here's a set of queries to shred the contents](https://gist.github.com/swasheck/11379661)) which will give you all kinds of information that you may, or may not be able to use (various levels of understanding are assumed when looking at the data).

If you can't access the actual event files, here's a query to get you started on the ring buffer. Then you can use the other queries with this as the base data.

```
select 
    event_timestamp = x.e.value('@timestamp','datetime2(3)'),
    event_data = x.e.query('.')
from (
            select 
                event_data = cast(target_data as xml)
                from sys.dm_xe_sessions xs
                join sys.dm_xe_session_targets xst
                    on xs.address = xst.event_session_address   
            where name = N'system_health'
                and xst.target_name = N'ring_buffer'
        ) base
cross apply base.event_data.nodes('//event') as x(e);
```

Additionally, there are stored procedures available in the community that may be able to help you with pulling specific information. I see @Kin has already provided my personal favorite, but for completeness it is:

[sp_WhoIsActive (a personal favorite)](http://whoisactive.com)

Note that your DBAs would need to create this stored procedure in order for you to be able to use it. Once installed, I find the `sp_WhoIsActive @help=1` documentation to be quite helpful.

In the event that you cannot persuade your DBAs to create this, I've written this query to pull a bunch of information that, hopefully, you can use.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 
GO
select   
    /*
        session values
    */
    s.session_id,
    s.login_time, 
    s.host_name, 
    s.program_name, 
    s.login_name, 
    s.status session_status, 
    s.date_format, 
    s.quoted_identifier, 
    s.arithabort, 
    s.ansi_defaults, 
    s.ansi_null_dflt_on, 
    s.ansi_warnings,
    s.ansi_nulls, 
    case s.transaction_isolation_level
        when 0 then 'Unspecified'
        when 1 then 'ReadUncommitted'
        when 2 then 'ReadCommitted'
        when 3 then 'Repeatable'
        when 4 then 'Serializable'
        when 5 then 'Snapshot'
    end as transaction_isolation_level,
    /*
        request values 
    */
    r.request_id, 
    r.status, 
    r.command,
    r.start_time request_start_time,    
    r.database_id request_database_id, 
    r.blocking_session_id request_blocking_session_id, 
    r.wait_type request_wait_type, 
    r.wait_time request_wait_time, 
    r.last_wait_type request_last_wait_type, 
    r.wait_resource request_wait_resource,  
    r.open_transaction_count, 
    r.percent_complete, 
    dateadd(millisecond,estimated_completion_time, sysdatetime()) estimated_completion_time, 
    r.granted_query_memory * 8 / 1024. request_granted_query_memory_mb,
    r.nest_level,
    r.executing_managed_code,
    /*
        task values 
    */
    t.task_address,
    t.task_state, 
    t.context_switches_count, 
    t.pending_io_count, 
    t.pending_io_byte_count, 
    t.scheduler_id, 
    t.exec_context_id, 
    /*
        memory grants values 
    */
    mg.dop as degrees_of_parallelism, 
    mg.requested_memory_kb / 1024. requested_memory_mb,
    mg.required_memory_kb / 1024. required_memory_mb,
    mg.granted_memory_kb / 1024. granted_memory_mb,
    mg.used_memory_kb / 1024. used_memory_mb,
    mg.max_used_memory_kb / 1024. max_used_memory_mb,
    mg.query_cost, 
    dateadd(second,mg.timeout_sec,sysdatetime()) memory_grant_timeout, 
    mg.queue_id,
    mg.is_next_candidate,
    mg.wait_time_ms memory_grant_wait_time, 
    case mg.is_small
        when 1 then 'Small Resource Semaphore'
        else 'Regular Resource Semaphore'
    end as memory_grant_resource_semaphore_type,
    mg.resource_semaphore_id,
    mg.pool_id,
    /* 
        query stats values
    */
    qs.creation_time plan_creation_time, 
    qs.last_execution_time, 
    qs.plan_generation_num,
    qs.execution_count, 
    qs.total_worker_time, 
    qs.last_worker_time, 
    qs.min_worker_time, 
    qs.max_worker_time, 
    qs.total_physical_reads, 
    qs.last_physical_reads, 
    qs.min_physical_reads,
    qs.max_physical_reads, 
    qs.total_logical_writes, 
    qs.last_logical_writes, 
    qs.min_logical_writes, 
    qs.max_logical_writes, 
    qs.total_logical_reads, 
    qs.last_logical_reads, 
    qs.min_logical_reads, 
    qs.max_logical_reads, 
    qs.total_clr_time, 
    qs.last_clr_time, 
    qs.min_clr_time, 
    qs.max_clr_time,
    qs.total_elapsed_time, 
    qs.last_elapsed_time, 
    qs.min_elapsed_time, 
    qs.max_elapsed_time,
    qs.total_rows,
    qs.last_rows, 
    qs.min_rows, 
    qs.max_rows,    
    (select       
            SUBSTRING(replace(replace(replace(text,CHAR(9),' '),char(10),' '),char(13), ' '),(r.statement_start_offset/2)+1,  
            (case when r.statement_end_offset = -1  
            then len(convert(nvarchar(max), qt.text)) * 2  
            else r.statement_end_offset end - r.statement_start_offset)/2+1) request_text, 
            text
            from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) qt
            for xml path('q'), type
            ) as sql_text, 
    qp.query_plan   
    from sys.dm_exec_sessions s 
    left join sys.dm_exec_requests r 
        on s.session_id = r.session_id  
    left join sys.dm_os_tasks t 
        on r.task_address = t.task_address      
    left join sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants mg
        on s.session_id = mg.session_id
        and r.scheduler_id = mg.scheduler_id    
    left join sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs 
        on mg.plan_handle = qs.plan_handle      
    --cross apply (

    --  select physical_memory_in_bytes / 1024. / 1024 server_memory_mb
    --      from sys.dm_os_sys_info
    --) mb
    --left join sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks wt
    --  on t.task_address = wt.waiting_task_address 
    --      and s.session_id = wt.session_id
    outer apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(mg.plan_handle) qp
    outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (mg.sql_handle) st 
where s.session_id > 50
    and s.session_id != @@SPID
option (recompile, maxdop 1);
```

Unfortunately, being a DBA is an entire career dedicated to learning what these things mean so I'm not sure how helpful much of this will be. It will give you an idea of what all is happening on your server at that moment to be able to help you formulate a more targeted question. As it stands, it could be server load. It could be a statistics issue. It could be OOM. It could be any number of things. To identify any of these would be a [book (hey, lookie there)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118177657) but hopefully this will provide a good starting point.